# ctools modal content size limit?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

Is there a limit to the amount of content that can be placed in a ctools modal window?  I looked at the ctools modal code, here on stackexchange, and did a Google search - no joy.

I'm upgrading a site for a client, and they want a modal window to display profile data for faculty members, but we're still supposed to pull that profile data from another one of their sites, as is.  We're doing the same thing, successfully, for another area of the upgraded site, but the data (obtained using file_get_contents()) is much smaller in size in that case.  Where I'm having problems, a typical page I'm supposed to fetch runs to about 62K.

I can successfully display a truncated version of a given page - though even then, I find I have the most success if I actually stop/re-start my browser (even flushing the cache doesn't seem to help as much) if I'm pushing the upper limit of what can be displayed, which is around 30k.

Anyone know where I'm running into a limit, and if it's configurable?

TIA,
Lee